# adding edge breaks graphviz dot layout

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am trying to make a vertical oriented flow chart in graphviz dot.  I'm new to this format so please go easy.  My layout is 99% correct, but when I add a final edge (`data -> h`) it breaks.  I've noticed that if I add the final edge, but remove the "yes" label, the format is also correct.  I've boiled this down to as simple of an example that still shows the undesired behavior.

My question:
How can I keep my desired vertical format, and keep the `data -> h` edge, and keep the "yes" label.

Ideal, but missing final edge:

[image: ideal_missing_edge]

Broken, with final `data -> h` edge:

[image]

Ideal, with final `data -> h` edge, but with "yes" label removed:

[image]

```
digraph G {

a [
label = "a";
shape = diamond;
];

b [
label = "b";
shape = rect;
];

makedata [
label = "makedata";
shape = rect;
];

data [
label = "data";
shape = box3d;
]

filldata [
label = "filldata";
shape = rect;
]

num [
label = "num"
shape = box3d;
]

num2 [
label = "num2"
shape = box3d;
]

prepdata [
label="prepdata"
shape=rect;
]

prepdata2 [
label="prepdata2"
shape=rect;
]

lorem [
label="lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit"
shape="rect"
]

lorem2 [
label="lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit"
shape="rect"
]

h [
label="h"
shape="rect"
]

{
rank=same;
filldata;data
}

{
rank=same;
num2;prepdata2
}

// if data -> h is included, and this label is removed, formatting is also correct
a:s -> b [label="Yes"]
b -> makedata
makedata:e -> data:w
makedata -> filldata [weight=99]
filldata:e -> data:w
filldata->prepdata  [weight=99]
data -> prepdata
data -> prepdata2
data -> lorem:ne
prepdata -> lorem:n  [weight=99]
lorem -> prepdata2  [weight=99]
num:e->prepdata:w 
num2:e->prepdata2:w [weight=99]
prepdata2:s -> lorem2:n [weight=99]
data -> lorem2
lorem2 -> h  [weight=99]
// data -> h  # the problem

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrangling edges is sometimes a hit-or-miss proposition.  Change your edge to terminate at h:ne (the northeast corner of h) like so:

```
data -> h:ne
```

And you get:
[image]

Comment: great! this worked for me.  Is there any other method beyond applying random weights or termination directions?

Comment: Invisible nodes on the right and left of any of the ranks might also do the trick.  Edge placement is quite opaque, but in this case you were probably(?) fighting rules about overall graph width/size and right/left edge symmetry (my guess).  Routing edges to/from ports is my "go to".

Comment: is there a way to increase graph width